# specific shipping cost by a product magento

Tags: product, magento-1.9

I have in magento configured the tablerates per weight

Now i have several products i must ship with specific amount
Is it possible to do when this product is in the cart there is a fix price for shipping.

Comment: Yes, it is possible, programmatically. You can for example add attribute to that specific product and then check if it's in the card.

Comment: i dont understand how do you mean

Answer (score 0):

you may try to add Shopping Cart Price Rule.

Go to magento Admin > Promotions > Shopping Cart Price Rule > Add New Rule

fill the froms.

On Conditions Tab use:

Shipping Method is SHIPPING_METHOD_NAME 
and another conditions for example for attribute sets.

Comment: Ok i understand how to do it with the Condition from the Attribute. But in the Action Tab for the Condition there are only discounts, i thnk this mean the price is after condition true cheaper.
But i want a fix shipping fee if the product in the cart

Comment: I think it that case you have to add extrafee as magento total. Please take a look on this link: http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2012/01/27/magento-add-fee-discount-order-total/

Comment: you may also override your shipping. to add amount conditionally.

Comment: there are a lot of possibility, but all of them are jobs for developer